# Map JavaScript file to an existing TypeScript type declaration

Tags: node.js, typescript-typings, pdf.js

I want to use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) within my TypeScript Node project using the NPM package [pdfjs-dist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist) (version 2.14.305). While `pdfjs-dist` contains type descriptions, the compiler cannot resolve the types in an specific case.

```
// type declarations at 'pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/node_utils';
import { NodeCanvasFactory } from 'pdfjs-dist/lib/display/node_utils';
```

The compiler complains about the types.

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module
> 'pdfjs-dist/lib/display/node_utils'.
> '[..]/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/lib/display/node_utils.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   If the 'pdfjs-dist' package actually
> exposes this module, try adding a new declaration (.d.ts) file
> containing `declare module 'pdfjs-dist/lib/display/node_utils';`

How can I tell `tsc` to take the types from `pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/node_utils`?